# Как сделать рабочим поле с телефоном в форме обратной связи?

Tags: php, html

Есть следующая форма

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form" style="    margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;">
Как к Вам обращаться:
<input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="фамилия имя отчество" x-autocompletetype="name">
Email для связи:
<input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="адрес электронной почты" x-autocompletetype="email">
Ваш номер телефона:
<input type="text" name="telFF" required placeholder="телефон" x-autocompletetype="tel">
Ваше сообщение:
<textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

и PHP обработчик

```
<?
if (array_key_exists('messageFF', $_POST)) {
   $to = 'info@fodrm.ru';
   $subject = 'Заполнена контактная форма с '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $subject = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";
   $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$_POST['contactFF']."\nТелефон: ".$_POST['telFF']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF']);
   $headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"';
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y h:i:s O') ."\r\n";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   echo $_POST['nameFF'];
}
?>
```

каким образом можно сделать поле номера телефона рабочим? т.е. что бы на почту приходило уведомление с формой, где есть не только Имя и адрес почты с сообщением, но и номер телефона?

Comment: А оно что не работает?

Comment: Сама форма перестает работать
Parse error; syntax error unexpected on line 6

Comment: line 6 какого файла?  и можно глянуть на эту 6 строку?)

Comment: как раз файл, где PHP обработчик)

Comment: 6я cтрочка там начинается как раз с $message

Comment: Сдается мне что там скобка ненужная $_POST['messageFF']);

Answer (score 0):

А что собственно ты открываешь на строке 6 что бы потом её закрывать ? :)

```
   $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$_POST['contactFF']."\nТелефон: ".$_POST['telFF']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
```

Эту строку вместо своей вставь:)  У тебя там была скобка лишняя.

Comment: Спасибо, форма работает. Но к сожалению письмо с формой телефона пустое. т.е. телефон указываю и на почту приходит сообщение с пустым полем рядом

Comment: А другие поля работают?

Comment: я разобрался! там просто надо было дописать формат отправки в яваскрипте

но меня смущает, что время на почте АМ, т.е. письмо пришло в 02:40, а не в 14:40

Comment: А ну это уже просто :  `$headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') ."\r\n"; `  укажите `h` с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Отпишешь о результате

Comment: Ага, работает! Спасибо!